# Back Button in IE shows plain xml instead of loading xsl stylesheet

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt, http-headers, back-button

IE has weird behaviour when pressing the back button. When trying to open a webpage, the server sends a `302` response that redirects the client to a login XML page with an XSL stylesheet. After the user successfully logged in, another page is loaded. However, when the user presses the "back button" and returns to the login page, IE shows only the raw XML values as plain text instead of executing the XSL stylesheet.

> All pages have "no-cache" policy.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: The question is how to let IE reload the page with xsl stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess or IIS configuration to check the ACCEPT request header for wildcards, then prevent parsing XML or XSLT files as plain text:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \*.\*$ 
ReWriteRule .*\.(xsl|xml)$ - [F]
```